# Conditional probability of two dependant continuous random variables

Tags: probability

I have

$f_{xy}(x,y) = 8xy$ if 0 < y < x < 1

which gives me

$f_x(x) = 4x^3$ if 0 < x < 1

$f_y(y) = 4y(1-y^2)$ if 0 < y < 1.

How do i then find $P(Y \leq 1/2 \ | \ X > 1/2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the definition of conditional probability:
$$
P(Y \leq 1/2 | X > 1/2) = \frac{P(Y \leq 1/2, X > 1/2)}{P(X > 1/2)}
= \frac{\int_{1/2}^1\int_{0}^{1/2} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\, dy\, dx}{\int_{1/2}^1\, f_X(x)\, dx}.
$$